# "no such file to load -- net/https" - Heroku, Ruby, Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, heroku, ubuntu-10.04

I've seen this problem posted in other blogs and stackoverflow threads, but no one seems to have the answer. I'm trying to run heroku and getting this error:

```
/usr/local/heroku/vendor/gems/rest-client-1.6.1/lib/restclient.rb:9:in `rescue in <top (required)>': no such file to load -- net/https. Try running apt-get install libopenssl-ruby (LoadError)
from /usr/local/heroku/vendor/gems/rest-client-1.6.1/lib/restclient.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/heroku/vendor/gems/rest-client-1.6.1/lib/rest_client.rb:2:in `require'
from /usr/local/heroku/vendor/gems/rest-client-1.6.1/lib/rest_client.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/client.rb:2:in `require'
from /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/client.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku.rb:3:in `require'
from /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/cli.rb:1:in `require'
from /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/cli.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/bin/heroku:29:in `require'
from /usr/bin/heroku:29:in `<main>'
```

Problem is that libopenssl-ruby is already the newest version.

Has anyone else come across this problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I Just had similar problem on my ubuntu 10.04, fixed it this way :

EDIT:

Quicker fix:
check */usr/local/heroku/bin/heroku* what version of ruby it is using
I had:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby1.9.1
```

Then install the right lib:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libopenssl-ruby1.9.1
```

---

Old:

Install rvm: http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/

To ~/.bashrc add:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

run:

```
$ source ~/.bachrc
```

Then:

```
$ rvm remove 1.9.2
$ rvm pkg install openssl
$ rvm install 1.9.2 -C --with-openssl-dir=$HOME/.rvm/usr
```

after running last command i had this output, note the ruby-1.9.2-p290:

```
Installing Ruby from source to: /my/home/dir/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)
```

then edit */usr/local/heroku/bin/heroku*
In first line change:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby1.9.1
```

To:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby-1.9.2-p290
```

you might need to install some missing libs for all of this to work, this will help to find what

```
$ rvm notes
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing it might be some permissions issue here, you should explain better how you installed your ruby, and secondly check if libopenssl-ruby is path of the current user, if its not then add it to its path.